# Getting Pandora App Song Information

Tags: android, pandora

Is there a way for a separate app to check what song is currently playing in the Pandora Android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know [Pandora® internet radio](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.pandora.android) is not open-source. Unless you are related to the Pandora project, you cant make an app to check the current song in Pandora. For that you'll need source. You can use decompilers to check the source but it's strongly **NOT RECOMMENDED**.